# python mocks cannot find reference 'assert_called_with' in 'function'

Tags: python, mocking, pycharm, pytest

I have these simple functions in python:

a.py

```
def fn1(a, b):
    return a + b


def fn1_reverted(a, b):
    return fn1(b, a)
```

and it's tests:

a_test.py

```
import a

def test_fn1():
    assert a.fn1('a', 'b') == 'ab'


def test_fn1_reverted(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(a, 'fn1')
    a.fn1_reverted('a', 'b')
    a.fn1.assert_called_with('b', 'a')
```

I am getting this warning by pycharm:
`Cannot find reference 'assert_called_with' in 'function'`

Am i doing something wrong?

Is this the correct way to assert that an internal function is called with specific params?

Comment: PyCharm's warning you that because it doesn't know you've patched it out - does it actually fail *at runtime*?

Comment: No, it works like a charm. I'm just new to python, and I want to make sure everything is okay, and I understand why it is. For example, for "return_value" method, I do not have that problem @jonrsharpe